# Spring specification query for one to many join and sum of field is grater then given value

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-jdbc, hibernate-criteria, spring-repositories

I am creating filter using joining this three entity **seeker_job_application**,**seeker_profile** and **seeker_experience**. where I want achieve result as below query.
In filter I want to find out **seeker_profile** whose **total_moth** of experience should be grater then or equal to given value i.e 20, one **seeker_profile** has multiple experience so I need to group by profile and sum of their experience and then compare with given value. is it possible to do this using spring specification?

How to check that seeker total month of experience is grater then or equal to given value?

**Relation between table is**
seeker_job_application 1<-->1 seeker_profile 1<---->* seeker_experience

**Want to achieve query like this**

```
select r.sja_id,r.sp_id,r.name,r.company_name,r.total_month from (
select sja.id as sja_id , sp.id as sp_id , sp.`name`,se.company_name,sum(se.total_month) as total_month 
from seeker_job_application sja 
INNER JOIN seeker_profile sp on sp.id = sja.seeker_id
INNER JOIN seeker_experience se on se.seeker_id = sp.id
where job_id =1 group by sp.id ) as r where r.total_month > 20;
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "seeker_job_application")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
public class SeekerJobApplication implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "seeker_id", nullable = false)
    private Long seekerId;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "job_id", nullable = false)
    private Long jobId;

    @Column(name = "apply_date")
    private Instant applyDate;

    @Column(name = "profile_viewed")
    private Boolean profileViewed;

    @Column(name = "on_hold")
    private Boolean onHold;

    @Column(name = "interview_schedule")
    private Boolean interviewSchedule;

    @Column(name = "rejected")
    private Boolean rejected;

    @Column(name = "selected")
    private Boolean selected;

    @Column(name = "prefered_location_id")
    private Long preferedLocationId;

    @Column(name = "work_preference")
    private String workPreference;

    @Column(name = "resume_file_path")
    private String resumeFilePath;

    @Column(name = "status")
    private String status;


    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="seeker_id",referencedColumnName = "id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private SeekerProfile seekerProfile;
```

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "seeker_profile")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
public class SeekerProfile implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "mobile_number", nullable = false)
    private String mobileNumber;

    @Column(name = "password")
    private String password;

    @Column(name = "email", nullable = false)
    private String email;

    @Column(name = "house_number")
    private String houseNumber;

    @Column(name = "address_line_1")
    private String addressLine1;

    @Column(name = "address_line_2")
    private String addressLine2;

    @Column(name = "city")
    private String city;

    @Column(name = "postcode")
    private String postcode;

    @Column(name = "state")
    private String state;

    @Column(name = "country")
    private String country;

    @Column(name = "website")
    private String website;

    @Column(name = "linkedin")
    private String linkedin;

    @Column(name = "facebook")
    private String facebook;

    @Column(name = "gender")
    private String gender;

    @Column(name = "dob")
    private String dob;

    @Column(name = "resume")
    private String resume;

    @Column(name = "wfh")
    private String wfh;

    @Column(name = "profile_completed")
    private String profileCompleted;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(unique = true)
    private Location preferedLocation;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "seeker_skill", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "seeker_id") }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "skill_id") })
    private Set<Skill> skills;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name="seeker_id",referencedColumnName = "id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Set<SeekerExperience> seekerExperiences;

    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name="seeker_id",referencedColumnName = "id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Set<SeekerEducation> seekerEducation;
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "seeker_experience")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
public class SeekerExperience implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "seeker_id", nullable = false)
    private Long seekerId;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "job_title", nullable = false)
    private String jobTitle;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "company_name", nullable = false)
    private String companyName;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "start_date", nullable = false)
    private String startDate;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "end_date", nullable = false)
    private String endDate;

    @Column(name = "total_month")
    private Integer totalMonth;

    @Column(name = "location")
    private String location;

    @Column(name = "role_description")
    private String roleDescription;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Specification<SeekerJobApplication> specification = Specification.where(null);
specification = specification.and((root, query, cb) -> {
            
Join<SeekerJobApplication, SeekerProfile> seekerProfile=root.join(SeekerJobApplication_.seekerProfile);
            Join<SeekerProfile, SeekerExperience> seekerExperience = seekerProfile.join(SeekerProfile_.seekerExperiences);
            query.having(cb.greaterThanOrEqualTo(cb.sum(seekerExperience.get(SeekerExperience_.totalMonth)), criteria.getTotalExperience().getEquals()));
     query.getRestriction();
            });
```

This will give me result as below query

```
select sja.* from seeker_job_application sja 
INNER JOIN seeker_profile sp on sja.seeker_id = sp.id
INNER JOIN seeker_experience se on se.seeker_id = sp.id
where sja.job_id = 1 
GROUP BY sp.id
having sum(se.total_month) > 20
```